# styling a dropdown menu using CSS

Tags: css

I have been trying to design a dropdown menu like following for my wordpress theme using CSS.

[image]

I have manged to create the dropdown but I cannot figure out how to create the curve using CSS and make the background color look transparent like in the image above.

To make it look transparent I tried `opacity:0.4; filter:alpha(opacity=40);` but it doesn't look near the dropdown menu above.

Could you please tell me how to make my dropdown look like the one in the image and make it responsive too?

Thanks

Here's my Code:

You can also check my code live here http://jsfiddle.net/MdpPd/

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Google</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Programs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>  

</nav>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 auto 0;
width: 100%;    
}

#menu ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding-left: 0;
position: absolute;
background: #108BB6;
}

#menu li {
float: left;
position: relative;

list-style-type: none;
}

#menu a {
display: block;
line-height: 2.4em;
padding: 0 13px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li {
display:block;
clear: both;
width: 265px;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
display: inline-block;
}

#menu li:not(:hover) ul {
display: none;
}

#menu ul ul {
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
display: none;
float: left;
position: absolute;
top: 2em;
left: 0;
z-index: 99999;
}

#menu ul ul ul {
left: 100%;
top: 0;
}

#menu ul ul a {
background: #dedede;
line-height: 1em;
padding: .5em .5em .5em 1em;
width: 10em;
height: auto;
}

#menu a:link {color:black;}
#menu a:visited {color:black;}
#menu a:focus {color:black; background: #ebdb00;}
#menu a:hover {color:white; background: #0C6481;}
#menu a:active {color:black; background: #ebdb00;}
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. In general, you should look into [CSS shapes](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) and [RGBA colors](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/)

Comment: I am thinking of offsetting each children progressively, and then using CSS borders to create those triangles...

And yes, you will need to rely on rgba() background-colour to have opacity in the background but not in the content.

Comment: @Boaz Thanks for your reply. I visited css-tricks.com earlier and tried `Parallelogram` code but the result was horrible. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/H8BLE/  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created the effect on the submenu using `:before` and `:after`.

Take a look at the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/rnPk5/2/).

It isn't the cleanest solution, but it works. 
It needs some adjusting from your side, but I hope this helps you on the way.

Comment: Thank you very much LinkinTED Your code has given me a good start. Lets see how can improve it more :)

Answer (score 1):

For giving curve to the Border you can use the

"border-radius" property in css.
like

```
border-radius: 5px; you can also use the border-(left,right,top,bottom) variations.
```

For giving the opacity to items

try giving color as "background-color: rgba(Redvalue, greenvalue, bluevalue, opacity value)".

like

```
background-color:rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the skew 'the curve' see http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp skew function

For the transparency: the example is less transparent (more like 0.9) and a lighter blue.  You could try asking the artist/designer as they probably know this

```
#menu ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding-left: 0;
position: absolute;
background: 10aBd6;
opacity: 0.9;
transform: skew(30deg,0deg);
-webkit-transform: skew(30deg,0deg);
-ms-transform: skew(30deg,0deg);
}
```

should get you going,  you'll need to 'unskew' the Text inside

```
#menu ul li {
display: block;
clear: both;
width: 265px;
    transform: skew(-30deg,0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg,0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg,0deg);
}
```

Comment: id say ,a perfect solution for the skew!

Comment: Put the link out there while I was writing it since, well, its 90% of that part of the answer!

Answer (score 0):

for the class=submenu use the below code to brig the skew

```
.submenu
{
   transform: skew(30deg,20deg);
   -ms-transform: skew(30deg,20deg); /* IE 9 */
 -webkit-transform: skew(30deg,20deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

the submenu would also use opaicity setting as you had already put ,to brig about the color just use background color you would like as in

```
.submenu{
 opacity:0.4; filter:alpha(opacity=40);
 background:blue;
```

}

to bring about responsive layout simply use common frameworks eg twitter bootstrap,project zurb

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your code but the result is this: http://i44.tinypic.com/1zg57jk.jpg :) thanks